# Stray voltage in RV/motorhome when running isolated grid

Tags: voltage

I was hoping to receive some thoughts reg following:

I'm running a 110VAC grid in my RV; power is being provided from 12V batteries that are connected to the inverter to convert to 110VAC and then feed the consumers. 12V negative is connected to chassis (like at any car) and the 110V earth is also connected to chassis (inverter and all consumers...and consequently also to 12V negative). The 110V neutral is NOT connected to earth. So, from what I think is that the earth in the motorhome is the chassis but at the same time somewhat floating as the chassis is not connected to ground (other than the tires which are pretty high resistor).

Now: I'm measuring 40VAC between Neutral and Earth. I cannot measure lowZ as I dont have a device. I tried measuring if there's actually any current between NEutral and Earth and there is none if I measure with a DMM. Once I disconnect the DMM (that provided a short between N and Earth) the voltage rises again to 40V.

If I disconnect all consumers the measured voltage seems to reduce..in other words, every MCB I put back in increases the measured voltage so this makes me think it's really just stray voltage.?

Just feels odd to have such a high voltage between N and Earth.

Can I connect N and E if I operate as an isolated grid (inverter type Giandel PS-3000KAR)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does the inverter user manual tell you to do with N and E?   Probably the output is fully isolated from the input and you can tie N and E together immediately at the output of the inverter.  I assume you have a set of breakers that include RCDs or similar.

Comment: I just ordered GFCI breakers to install them over the weekend, had the same thought. Now, I would really be tempted to tie N and E but cant find anything in the manual: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91J1cZpTB9L.pdf?spm=..collection_0a2439be-a07d-403d-995c-2f7539d1b185.header_1.1&spm_prev=..article_ade12d28-195e-45fb-8f9d-ce52d454bbe3.header_1.1